# Stylelint selector-max-specificity: class::placeholder (0,0,1) doesn't but class:focus::placeholder (0,1,1) throws error with 0.2.0 max specificity

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, css-specificity, stylelint

I am trying to reduce CSS specificity in my project by using the stylelint selector-max-specificity and I have now set it to "0.2.0". The problem is that when I use `wonderful-input::placeholder` it doesn't throw me an error, even if it has 0,0,1 specificity, but when I use `wonderful-input:focus::placeholder` the specificity is increased to 0,1,1 and an error is thrown. The error that I get ofc is:

> Expected ".input-basic__input--active:focus::placeholder" to have a
> specificity no more than "0,2,0"
> (selector-max-specificity)Stylelint(selector-max-specificity)

Does anyone know why I get the error and if I can decrease the specificity on this one?

I just don't understand why 0,0,1 doesn't and 0,1,1 does throw me an error! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know why I get the error

Using [this calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) you can see that the selector `.input-basic__input--active:focus::placeholder` has a specificity of `0,2,1`, i.e. 2 (pseudo-)classes and 1 (pseudo-)element.

`0,2,1` is greater than chosen max specificity of `0,2,0`, and the rule correctly reports this.

You should increase your primary option to `0,2,1` if you want to use this selector.

> the problem is that when I use `wonderful-input::placeholder` it doesn't throw me an error

The selector `wonderful-input::placeholder` has a specificity of `0,0,2`, i.e. 2 (pseudo-)elements, which is lower than `0,2,0` so the rule allows it.

> can I decrease the specificity on this one?

There is no way to decrease the specificity of the `.input-basic__input--active:focus::placeholder` selector and have it do the same thing: i.e. style the `placeholder` pseudo-element of focused elements that have the class `input-basic__input--active`.

> I am trying to reduce CSS specificity in my project by using the stylelint selector-max-specificity

It's an admirable goal. You can also use the [other `selector-max-*` rules](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list#selector-1), like `selector-max-class`, `selector-max-combinators`, `selector-max-compound-selectors` and so on, to help you do this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you for your answer, appreciate it :)